# bxSlider WP Pro Multiple themed pagers

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, bxslider, pager

I bought bxSlider WP Pro. Everything is working fine. I just want to create several pager templates. Let's say I have a slider on the front page with blue pager and I have a slider in an inside page with red pager.

Any ideas of how to do that? I will be grateful if anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: You could try using the body tags to create per page css styles for the pager.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. The pagers CSS loading by the plugin. All the sliders are reading that file for the styling. Can I create overwrites for that CSS?

Comment: yes, inspect the page using firebug or something similar. Look at the body tag of the page  for the class that's added then check out the tag used for the pager. Then combine and add that to your sites own css.

Comment: That's not a manual created plugin. Is the original plugin for Wordpress. The tag for the pager is always the same. On the plugins settings at the back-office, you cannot add your own CSS to overwrite that default one.

Comment: So you don't have access to the sites own css (not the plugins)?

Comment: Let me check this one and I will come back. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out.

For people that want to make several pager styles for pages, you have to load your custom CSS file to the head of the particular page. Keep the same class names and just change your styling and your done.